# How to represent aggregate entities using Code-First?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have recently started developing using ASP.NET and am struggling to grasp Code-First. I am working on a project for an internship and have very little database knowledge except for one class I've taken. I am in no way asking for a complete solution or being lazy.

I've been trying for a couple days to create a solid ER diagram and I'm fairly certain the one below will represent all of the information I need to store. Please let me know if you see any ways this can be improved.

**What I'm trying to do:**

For this project an administrator will create rooms with attributes listed below. The admin will then assign time-slots that represent between what hours the room will be available and what days of the week it will be available.

The users will fill out their basic information and fill out a form representing what times they are available.

After all the users have registered the admin will run a scheduling algorithm to come up with the closest to a most efficient schedule that it can (because it's NP hard).

The assigned relation represents user time slots that are related to room time slots in order to produce a table of what users are assigned to what rooms at what times.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

**Questions**

1. How would I represent these aggregate entities using Code-First? Not necessarily asking for the code for this exact diagram but maybe quick example to help me wrap my head around Code-First.
2. Do my mappings look correct for these relations?

Any help or point in the right direction is greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Below is an ER diagram that represents the following:

- Room (id, number, building, capacity)
- TimeSlot (id, startHour, endHour, dayOfWeek)
- User (id, firstName, lastName, email)
- Available (userId, timeID)
- Reserved (roomID, timeID)
- Assigned (reservedID, availableID)

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: This is a full project, I really do not know what do you expect as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in the ER diagram I would have expected a link directly from Room to TimeSlot (top-right) and User to Timeslot (bottom right), but knowing the likely queries that will be run I would suggest the ERD should be as follows.

Room linked to an entity called RoomAvailability. RoomAvailability contains all the free time slots for rooms, so this will initially be populated with one record per room per day (RoomId, Date, StartTime, EndTime) going to as many days into the future as you think necessary.

Similarly I would have an entity UserAvailability (UserId, Date, StartTime, EndTime) linked to User.

Entity RoomReservation (RoomId, UserId, Date, StartTime, EndTime) linked to both Room and User which contains all room reservations (assumes only 1 user can book a room).

When a room is reserved a RoomReservation records is added and a single RoomAvailability record may be split into 2 separate ones  (e.g. room is free for whole day then someone books a slot during the day leaving 2 free periods at the start and end of the day).

When a reservation is cancelled the RoomReservation record is deleted and 2 RoomAvailability records may be merged back into 1 (the reverse of the above).

I believe that splitting and merging of available slots is how similar systems work.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I forgot to mention that a room is available to multiple users when it's free. Not just one user reserving a room. Sort of like a movie theater room.

Comment: That makes it more interesting. Include freeCapacity in RoomAvailability and the link between RoomReservation and User becomes a many-to-many mapping